# Unable to display the min and max of sum based on a particular data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to display the min and max total order of item based on the restaurant. I am able to display the min and max of the total order base on this code.

```
(SELECT mx.name, max(mx.total) Max_order
FROM
   (SELECT     m.name, sum(ol.quantity_order) total
    FROM       menu m, orderlist ol
    WHERE      ol.menu_id = m.menu_id
    GROUP BY   m.name, ol.menu_id) mx
GROUP BY mx.name 
ORDER BY Max_order desc
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
UNION ALL
(SELECT mn.name, min(mn.total) Max_order
FROM
    (SELECT     m.name, sum(ol.quantity_order) total
     FROM       menu m, orderlist ol
     WHERE      ol.menu_id = m.menu_id
     GROUP BY   m.name, ol.menu_id) mn
GROUP BY mn.name 
ORDER BY Max_order asc
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY);
```

But when I tried to display based on restaurant i am unable to display the min and max item ordered

```
(SELECT  m.menu_id, m.name, fin.Max_order AS
         Total_Order
FROM
    (SELECT mx.name, max(mx.total) Max_order
    FROM
       (SELECT     m.name, sum(ol.quantity_order) total
        FROM       menu m, orderlist ol
        WHERE      ol.menu_id = m.menu_id
        GROUP BY   m.name, ol.menu_id) mx
    GROUP BY mx.name 
    ORDER BY Max_order desc
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT mn.name, min(mn.total) Max_order
    FROM
        (SELECT     m.name, sum(ol.quantity_order) total
         FROM       menu m, orderlist ol
         WHERE      ol.menu_id = m.menu_id
         GROUP BY   m.name, ol.menu_id) mn
    GROUP BY mn.name 
    ORDER BY Max_order asc
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)fin
WHERE    ol.menu_id = m.menu_id AND
         m.restaurant_id = r.restaurant_id AND
         r.restaurant_name = &Restaurant
ORDER BY fin.Max_order
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY);
```

This is the error that i got but i am pretty sure that i had close everything correctly.

```
ERROR at line 22:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry i don't really get what u meant. Are you suggesting me to post some sample data? @GordonLinoff

Comment: @GilsonLim yes please.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it much easier with querying each table just once:

```sql
      select
        max(name) keep(dense_rank first order by total asc) min_name,
        min(total) as min_total,
        max(name) keep(dense_rank first order by total desc) max_name,
        max(total) as max_total
      from (
        SELECT     m.name, sum(ol.quantity_order) total
        FROM       menu m, orderlist ol
                 -- ,restaurant r
        WHERE      ol.menu_id = m.menu_id
          -- add whatever is r alias into from clause and then you can uncomment this:
         --and m.restaurant_id = r.restaurant_id AND r.restaurant_name = &Restaurant
        GROUP BY   m.name, ol.menu_id
      );
```

*Unfortunately you haven't specified which table has `r` alias, so I commented out a couple of strings related to `r`. If that table is `restaurant`, you can uncomment them or modify table name in them.*

Full example with sample data:

```sql
with menu(menu_id,name) as (
select 1, 'menu1' from dual union all
select 2, 'menu2' from dual union all
select 3, 'menu3' from dual union all
select 4, 'menu4' from dual 
)
,orderlist(menu_id,quantity_order) as (
select 1, 1 from dual union all
select 2, 1 from dual union all
select 2, 2 from dual union all
select 3, 1 from dual union all
select 3, 2 from dual union all
select 3, 3 from dual union all
select 4, 1 from dual union all
select 4, 2 from dual union all
select 4, 3 from dual union all
select 4, 4 from dual
)
      select
        max(name) keep(dense_rank first order by total asc) min_name,
        min(total) as min_total,
        max(name) keep(dense_rank first order by total desc) max_name,
        max(total) as max_total
      from (
        SELECT     m.name, sum(ol.quantity_order) total
        FROM       menu m, orderlist ol
        WHERE      ol.menu_id = m.menu_id
          -- add whatever is r alias into from clause and then you can uncomment this:
         --and m.restaurant_id = r.restaurant_id AND r.restaurant_name = &Restaurant
        GROUP BY   m.name, ol.menu_id
      );
```

Result:

```
MIN_N  MIN_TOTAL MAX_N  MAX_TOTAL
----- ---------- ----- ----------
menu1          1 menu4         10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a pair of brackets around the UNION ALL Selects, it's a Derived Table/Inline Select:

```
SELECT  m.menu_id, m.name, fin.Max_order AS
         Total_Order
FROM
 ( -- added
    (SELECT mx.name, max(mx.total) Max_order
    FROM
       (SELECT     m.name, sum(ol.quantity_order) total
        FROM       menu m, orderlist ol
        WHERE      ol.menu_id = m.menu_id
        GROUP BY   m.name, ol.menu_id) mx
    GROUP BY mx.name 
    ORDER BY Max_order desc
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT mn.name, min(mn.total) Max_order
    FROM
        (SELECT     m.name, sum(ol.quantity_order) total
         FROM       menu m, orderlist ol
         WHERE      ol.menu_id = m.menu_id
         GROUP BY   m.name, ol.menu_id) mn
    GROUP BY mn.name 
    ORDER BY Max_order asc
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
 ) fin -- added
WHERE    ol.menu_id = m.menu_id AND
         m.restaurant_id = r.restaurant_id AND
         r.restaurant_name = &Restaurant
ORDER BY fin.Max_order
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

But I doubt this will return anything usefull due to all those `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY`. You get a single row only, never the max total.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic function such as `ROW_NUMBER()` `PARTITION`ED `BY` **menu name** and **restaurant id** after determining the number of orders `GROUP`ED `BY` **menu name** and **restaurant id** :

```
WITH orders AS
(
  SELECT m.name, 
         m.restaurant_id,
         SUM(ol.quantity_order) AS total_order         
    FROM menu m
    JOIN orderlist ol
      ON ol.menu_id = m.menu_id
    JOIN restaurant r
      ON r.restaurant_id = m.restaurant_id  
   GROUP BY m.restaurant_id, m.name   
), orders2 AS
(
SELECT name,
       restaurant_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY restaurant_id, name ORDER BY total_order DESC) 
          AS max_order,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY restaurant_id, name ORDER BY total_order) 
          AS min_order
  FROM orders
)
SELECT 'Max. # Of Orders' AS "Order Status", name, restaurant_id 
  FROM orders2 WHERE max_order = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Min. # Of Orders', name, restaurant_id 
  FROM orders2 WHERE min_order = 1
```

where `restaurant` is a presumed name of the missing table which's aliased with `r` within the question.